# Django using python

Tags: django

1.Kindly tell how can we set the limit for integer fields in django .

2.Kindly tell the codings for the block name (Add Another Choice) should be of limited for the program

```
class Record(models.Model):
    Name   = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True,help_text="Employee Name")
    Empid  = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,help_text="Employee ID")
    Salary = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    Bonus  = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
class Choice(models.Model):
    p=models.ForeignKey(Record)
    Month=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither can be done at the ORM level; you will need to add database-level constrains using raw SQL.

Answer (score 0):

1 If you just want to check user input use a clean method

ie.

```
def clean_bonus(self): #thus: clean_FIELDNAME
    #check the value and show an error
```

2 I am not sure what you mean:

a) If you mean you want users to select atleast 1 choice, but limit the maximum use something like this:

```
class RequireOneFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    """
    Require at least one form in the formset to be completed.
    """
    def clean(self):
        """Check that at least one form has been completed."""
        super(RequireOneFormSet, self).clean()
        for error in self.errors:
            if error:
                return
        completed = 0
        for cleaned_data in self.cleaned_data:
            # form has data and we aren't deleting it.
            if cleaned_data and not cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False):
                completed += 1

        if completed < 1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("At least one %s is required." %
                self.model._meta.object_name.lower())
```

b) If you mean you want to have multiple foreign keys use django ContentTypes